# Bitcoin fork! can I gain access to the coins

Tags: bitcoin-cash, btce

I wanted to know - I got some 1.18 BTC on blockchain.info and I noticed just now that there are allot of hard forks happened till now.
how is it possible to gain the coins from those hard forks ...and are those still live?

Name---Fork from---Fork height

Clashic Bitcoin 478559
Gold    Bitcoin 491407
Cash    Clashic 504032
2X  Gold    494784
Diamond Bitcoin 495866
SuperBitcoin    Bitcoin 498888

Answer (score 1):

You can access your coins in blockchain.info only if blockchain.info announces will support the fork. 
Remember you should have bitcoin on your account before hardfork.

Comment: AFAIK blockchain.info gives you access to the private keys, so in principle you can access the forked coins with or without their cooperation.  The process may be a bit complicated for newbies, however.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of useless hardforks and some prices will go to 0 in my oppinion. There are only futures for 5 of your hardfork coins ( example: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-diamond/ )

But Bitcoin Gold was at least a "sucessfull" hardfork ( https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-gold/ ) and you could sell them. The price is around 300$ per BTG at the moment.

You need to transfer them to an exchange that accepts BTG.